# Listener for video is running

Tags: android

Hi guys i'm developing a android application...
There is a listener for the "When the video is in playing"?
i know the listner

```
 videoView.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener()
```

THIS IS A LISTENER.
i want a listener for: when the video is running... is possible?

```
 public void PlayVideo(String dir){

     final VideoView videoView =(VideoView)findViewById(R.id.videoView);
        MediaController mediaController= new MediaController(this);
        mediaController.setAnchorView(videoView);        
        Uri uri=Uri.parse(dir);        
        videoView.setMediaController(mediaController);
        videoView.setVideoURI(uri);        
        videoView.requestFocus();

        videoView.start();

        videoView.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() 
        {           
            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) 
            {
                VideoInPlay = false;
             videoView.start();

            }           
        });  
}
```

Thank you so much and sorry for my english!

Comment: "When the video is in playing" are you talking about a listener for when it starts? You could just do something after .start() or create a custom listener

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a which returns a boolean value.

```
 videoView.isPlaying();
```

It will return true if a video is playing